# Can't save text file with C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, file, pointers, save

I think I have those pointers issues again. I have created a simple function that saves a char array into a specified file. **This is all my code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void Output(const char*, const char*, const char*);
void OutPutSomething();

// main.cpp --------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char Message[256];
    snprintf(Message, 256, "This message will be saved\n");
    Output("Output.txt", Message, "w");
    return 0;
}

void OutPutSomething() {
    Output("Output.txt", "This text will not be saved (???)\n", "w");
}

void Output(const char *FileName, const char *Text, const char *Mode) {
    FILE *OutputFIle;
    OutputFIle = fopen(FileName, Mode);
    if (OutputFIle != NULL) {
        printf(Text, "\n");
        fputs(Text, OutputFIle);
        fclose(OutputFIle);
    } else {
        printf("Output function failed!");
    }
}
```

So, my problem is this: when called from the main function the `Output()` function woks correctly - the text is saved in the file. Yet, when I call the `Output()` function from `OutPutSomething()` it doesn't save the text into the file properly (it only saves a '\B0' text). I see the text that `printf()` shows in the console but the text is not saved.

What could be the cause? Thanks!

**MORE:**
I use Code::Blocks (GCC compiler) and the application is a console application. No libraries linked, no other headers added. Frustrating to see that such simple things don't work.

Comment: You typically shouldn't be defining your functions inside your header files. The header typically only declares the function signature, and the definition should reside elsewhere in a `.cpp` file which can be independently compiled and then linked into the final binary.

Comment: Is this the complete code? #include <stdio.h> seems to be missing.

Comment: This doesn't look like C++ code, it's more like C code.

Comment: Works here, too, like for everybody else.

Comment: Perhaps you are running some other code than what is shown here? For example, you might be working with a file called "Main.h", but there is another, older version called "main.h", and that is the one that is actually used? Or you're editing a file called "main.h", but in the wrong directory?

Comment: Did you use a debugger to find your issue? Did you compile your source code with debugging information, and all warnings enabled? Did you `strace` a faulty execution??

Comment: `OutputSomething` is not called in your example!

Comment: If I, in your new updated code, replace the call to `Output` from `main` with a call to `OutPutSomething`, it stores the text "This text will not be saved (???)\n" in the file "Output.txt". Your problem must be somewhere else. Start by using strace or single-step through the program with a debugger.

Comment: If I open the file in "a+" mode then instead of the same 2 weird characters I get a string of weird characters. This is so f***ing crazy. I'm going back to Windows.

Comment: I can't even use "string" (was not declared in this scope ???). I include the header, use the namespace but no string. My compiler must be some piece of sh*t.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine on my system. I agree with the others that you shouldn't put function implementations in your header files though.

Comment: Works on my system too. There must be some other problem, not part of the code shown here.